# Laravel 5.2 with AngularJS2

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel-5

I want to use laravel 5.2 with angularjs2. I want to use javascript for that. I could not find any good resource on how to do it ? Could anyone help me this?

Comment: use vuejs, that is lite and perfect to use with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how to use Laravel as an API and try to access that API from Angularjs2 application and send the request as you needed.

You can visit the website to know how to use laravel as an api. 
[Laravel As A Rest API](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjz2s7i_rbSAhWBXRoKHSOxAvsQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.tutsplus.com%2Fcourses%2Fbuild-a-rest-api-with-laravel&usg=AFQjCNFLGZWNXpuu29qQ5a3rqPhbB9rr1Q&bvm=bv.148747831,d.d2s)

You can visit the website to know how to use http request in angularjs2
[Angularjs2 Http Request](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/)

Merging these two things, you can use Laravel and Angularjs2. :)